# Multidimension array versus nested lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Aside from the different accessing methods (e.g. `[1,2]` instead of `[1][2]` to access element in 2nd row and 3rd column), what are the differences between multidimensional arrays and nested lists in python? Why are both data structures necessary?

Comment: The difference is: nested lists exists in the python standard library, multidimensional arrays not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python does not *have* a *multidimensional* array type. It only has lists.

[`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) (a 3rd-party Python extension) does have array types, and these serve a specialized function within that library, namely fast C-based mathematical operations on homogenous sequences.

With the standard Python `list` type, putting one inside the other creates a nested structure that *can* be used to model a multidimensional structure. You nest the `[index]` item access, `[1][42]` first retrieves the second element of the outer list, then the 43rd element of that second element.

`numpy` arrays are specialist structures that explicitly model multiple dimensions as part of the main type, rather than nesting arrays inside arrays, and that means they can support addressing of multiple dimensions in the `[index]` syntax, where `index` comes in the form of a tuple, technically.

Python does have a *single dimensional* [`array` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html), that, like `numpy` arrays, models homogenous C-type sequences.

Comment: @hivert: but that is not **multidimensional**.